# Java: Minimum spanning tree with JGraphT?

Tags: java, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, jgrapht

I have a problem that can essentially be viewed as a graph. I'm considering using JGraphT to implement it instead of rolling my own. What would be the best way to get a minimum spanning tree out of a graph using JGraphT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know enough graph theory to give you a complete, direct answer, but I have used jgrapht in a few projects, so maybe this will help.

The list of algorithms included with jgrapht is here: http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/package-summary.html, and you can also find graph traversals implemented as iterators (if that is any help) here: http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/traverse/package-summary.html

I'm pretty sure none of those algorithms will get you want you want out of the box, so you'd have to code it yourself, but I can tell you from experience that coding on top of jgrapht as opposed to starting from scratch is A LOT easier.  There is also a [FibonacciHeap](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/util/FibonacciHeap.html) class that would presumably help with implementing Prim's algorithm.

If you need help with the algorithm itself, there are a number of algorithms with Wikipedia entries, with detailed descriptions and pseudocode.  The [Minimum spanning tree article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) links to them.

Answer (score 2):

[Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) has an implementation of this.

Answer (score 1):

[ClosestFirstIterator](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/traverse/ClosestFirstIterator.html) may help you out. It builds a spanning tree using FibonacciHeap while iterating over the vertices.

ClosestFirstIterator provides the methods getShortestPathLength() and getSpanningTreeEdge() to get parts of the minimum spanning tree.

```
// instantiate the iterator
ClosestFirstIterator<V,E> it = new ClosestFirstIterator<V,E>(graph, start_vertex);

// iterate to build the tree
while(it.hasNext())
  it.next();

// query
double distance = getShortestPathLength(vertex);
E next_edge = getSpanningTreeEdge(vertex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions of the JGraphT library have various choices for an MST algorithm, no need to implement one from scratch.

The following code works with Java 8 and JGraphT version 1.3.0. It computes the minimum spanning tree of a small graph using the algorithms by (a) Prim, (b) Kruskal and (c) Borůvka. Details about the different algorithms can be found in the wikipedia article about the [mst problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).

```
package org.myorg.mstdemo;

import org.jgrapht.Graph;
import org.jgrapht.alg.spanning.BoruvkaMinimumSpanningTree;
import org.jgrapht.alg.spanning.KruskalMinimumSpanningTree;
import org.jgrapht.alg.spanning.PrimMinimumSpanningTree;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.builder.GraphTypeBuilder;
import org.jgrapht.util.SupplierUtil;

/**
 * MST demo
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = GraphTypeBuilder
                .undirected()
                .weighted(true)
                .allowingMultipleEdges(false)
                .allowingSelfLoops(false)
                .vertexSupplier(SupplierUtil.createStringSupplier())
                .edgeSupplier(SupplierUtil.createDefaultWeightedEdgeSupplier())
                .buildGraph();

        String v0 = graph.addVertex();
        String v1 = graph.addVertex();
        String v2 = graph.addVertex();

        DefaultWeightedEdge e1 = graph.addEdge(v0, v1);
        DefaultWeightedEdge e2 = graph.addEdge(v1, v2);
        DefaultWeightedEdge e3 = graph.addEdge(v0, v2);

        graph.setEdgeWeight(e1, 100d);
        graph.setEdgeWeight(e2, 5d);
        graph.setEdgeWeight(e3, 1d);

        System.out.println("Prim:");
        for(DefaultWeightedEdge e: new PrimMinimumSpanningTree<>(graph).getSpanningTree()) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Kruskal:");
        for(DefaultWeightedEdge e: new KruskalMinimumSpanningTree<>(graph).getSpanningTree()) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Borůvka:");
        for(DefaultWeightedEdge e: new BoruvkaMinimumSpanningTree<>(graph).getSpanningTree()) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```